# Find number of files in directory that has been created specific year

Tags: files, find, date

I would like to get the number of files in a directory and its sub-directories (recursively) that was created year 2016. I only care about files that has a specific file ending, for example ".txt". How can I achieve this in the terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With GNU `find`:

```
find /some/dir -type f -name '*.txt' -printf '%CY\n' | grep -Fxc 2016
```

This counts the files with a `ctime` in 2016 in the local timezone.  Please note that `ctime` is not the creation time of the files, but it's about the best approximation of it you can hope for with standard UNIX semantics.

If you want to match modification time you can use `-printf '%TY\n'` above instead of `-printf '%CY\n'`.

Comment: One might argue that the mtime is a better representation of the age of a file as it's the age of its content. ctime if the last time its status was changed which also happens when the permissions of the file changed or sometimes when it's renamed or linked. One advantage may be that the ctime can't be forged. When you extract a tar archive for instance, you get the mtime as stored in the archive and the ctime corresponding to the time of extraction (shortly later than Btime), which one you'd want depends on context.

Answer (score 4):

This is a portable way which doesn't require `GNUfind`.

First create files with a timestamp in it

```
touch -t 201601010000 /tmp/2016 && touch -t 201701010000 /tmp/2017
```

Then execute.

```
find /some/path -type f -name '*.txt'  -newer /tmp/2016 ! -newer /tmp/2017
```

Comment: Since `-newer` compares `mtime`s, not `ctime`s, this solves your re-interpretation of the problem, not the problem as stated.

Comment: @SatōKatsura To be fair, `ctime` is not *creation* time either, it's *change* time.  There's no standard UNIX way to get file creation times.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU  `find` and on systems and file systems supporting file *birth time*:

```
find . -name '*.txt' -type f -newerBt 2016-01-01 \
                           ! -newerBt 2017-01-01 -printf . | wc -c
```

Technically that would exclude files created at the 2016-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 nanosecond and include the ones created at that nanosecond in 2017 (I don't expect your clock would have that precision or that it matters anyway, but it could matter on file systems that don't support subsecond timestamps for files created by cron jobs at 00:00:00 for instance)

It your system doesn't support birth time, you could revert to last modification time (which is probably better anyway as the birth time is the time the file was instantiated (not necessarily by that name), not the time the data in it was written so has little relevance in practice), by changing `newerBt` to `newermt`.

With BSD `find` (where those `-newerxy` come from), you can change it to:

```
find .//. -name '*.txt' -type f -newerBt 2016-01-01 \
                              ! -newerBt 2017-01-01 | grep -c //
```